# Strange Google Colab ping result

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

When I try to use ping in colab I get:

```
!ping binance.com
/bin/bash: ping: command not found
```

The quick reference guide is not showing ping:

```
%quickref
```

But using os library seems to execute the ping command:

```
import os
os.system("ping binance.com")
32512
```

What is the meaning of the result? (32512)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think at this time, there is no other ways of using a terminal in google colab unless you pay for the pro. The 32512 in ping means **Keys expired.**

```
 import os
 hostname = "binance.com" 
 response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + hostname)
 
 if response == 0:
  print(hostname, 'Connected')
else:
  print(hostname, 'Connect Fail')
```

You can try this code and should give you a clearer result which is **'Connect Fail'** In the past, you can use Teleconsole, however it was shut down since 04.09.2021